# Faveod Designer : How to hide items in navigation menu for which the user does not have permissions to access

Tags: code-generation

So I have a resource (aka Maveoc) named `Department` that is configured as `Visible in Menu`.

In the generated app, the link to this resource/Maveoc is visible to all users, including those that do not have the permissions to access it.

From a security point of view, this is not a problem since it's not possible for the users to access that page.

It would be however nice to hide the link for the users that do not have access to it.

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the boolean `:check_access` option  in `link_to_action` does.

In graphical mode or if you specify a view's options, just check the checkbox.

Feel free to browse `/macros_references` in the Designer.
We know it's a tedious read for now: feedback is welcome,
and be sure that our V3 will have a much cleaner doc page.